# Install anomalize package in R

Tags: r, installation, anomaly-detection

I have upgraded R version to R.3.6.2 and then installed tidyverse 1.3.0 Then I have installed anomalize package, but when I load anomalize it gives me this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘anomalize’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'anomalize', details:
  call: NULL
  error: Function getThemeInfo not found in RStudio
```

The OS is ubunto 18.04.3
Could you please let me know what is this problem and how I can fix it.

Comment: Are you using the R GUI or RStudio? If the latter, what version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: I am using rstudio version 1.0.143

Comment: Yikes. That’s a pretty old version. If possible, I suggest you try to upgrade RStudio, or just try the code using the plain R GUI.

Comment: I run R 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 and the current version of RStudio. Installing `anomalize` works without any problems. You should follow @MrFlick 's advice and upgrade RStudio.

Comment: Thank you I will upgarde r studio as well